# There is no web named - Sharepoint Event Hander

Tags: sharepoint, document, event-handling, create-directory

I activated following code with feature (web level scope). Now when I add an item to any document library it should create a folder "".

No folder is created and no error is given either? Can anyone see what is going on? I got the following from the log file. I found similar code all over google so I am kinda puzzled why is not working in my environment?

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace AddaFolder
{
    class clAddaFolder : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
            using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                try
                { 
                //SPListTemplateCollection coll = currentWeb.ListTemplates;

                //Get the current document library link
                SPList newList = currentWeb.GetList(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
                    //.Site.Url);
                //newList = currentWeb.Lists.Add("My TEST Folder",SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder);
                //newList.Lists.Items.Add("My TEST Folder", SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder);
                //newList.Update();               

                SPListItem newListItem;
                //newListItem = newList.Folders.Add("", SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, "My Test Folder");
                newListItem = newList.Folders.Add(newList.ToString(), SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, "My Test Folder");
                newListItem.Update();              
                }
                catch (SPException spEx)
                {
                    throw spEx;                
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

log file

```
04/03/2010 17:52:44.25  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:44.26  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/My TEST Doc Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:44.27  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:44.29  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:44.30  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Team Discussion/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:44.31  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:44.32  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/My TEST Doc Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:44.34  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:44.35  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:44.36  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Team Discussion/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:51.33  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:51.34  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/My TEST Doc Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:51.35  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:51.37  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:51.38  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Team Discussion/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:51.39  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:51.40  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/My TEST Doc Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:51.41  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:51.43  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:52:51.44  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Team Discussion/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:53:02.69  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:53:02.71  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/My TEST Doc Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:53:02.72  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:53:02.73  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:53:02.74  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Team Discussion/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:53:02.75  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:53:02.76  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/My TEST Doc Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:53:02.77  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:53:02.78  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx".  
04/03/2010 17:53:02.79  w3wp.exe (0x00C0)                        0x0C88 Windows SharePoint Services    General                        8kh7 High     There is no Web named "/sites/myDevSiteColl/myDevWeb/Lists/Team Discussion/AllItems.aspx".
```

Comment: There's a few things wrong here... I'd suggest cleaning up your code example above and we can comment better.

Answer (score 1):

I see two major problems there:

- SPContext.Current.Web.Url is the url of a web, not a list.
- SPList has a RootFolder property that would probably be more appropriate than ToString()

Answer (score 0):

SPContext.Current - at least in my experience - is for some reason null in event listeners; instead, get at the current SPWeb and SPSite through the relevant properties in the SPItemEventProperties parameter *(and do not use them in "using" since that would make them disposed for later processing)*.